# SQL Server Web Edition Installation

Tags: installation, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a hosted VM with about 20 client websites on board. Many use a database which is currently SQL Server 2008 R2 (not an evaluation). Because of upcoming licensing issues, I need to change to the Web Edition of SQL Server with my current host. Is it possible to install SQL Server Web Edition on a box that already has SQL Server 2008 R2 installed?

If it's not possible, could someone suggest best process for this switch?

Comment: You may also find useful [Downgrading SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard to Web Edition](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/30226/10618) on our sister site [dba.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple SQL Server editions are allowed to be installed on the same box.  There will just be choices if you want to minimize your downtime.

Normally SQL Server Editions are installed with the default name so the connect string you are using is likely 192.0.x.x and valid.  The new edition will be have to be named something else.  192.0.x.x\MyChoosing or defaults to 192.0.x.x\SQLEXPRESS.  This is option will be present during initial install of MSSQL.

1. Install the web edition.
2. Make a backup copies of database(s) (through the SQL Server Manager, it is a right click option)
3. Import the database(s) into the SQL Web Edition
4. Optional (recommended):  Create a copy of your web server (or at least one site).  Put it on a different port for testing
5. Update your connection strings
6. Swap backup site onto main port (80, 443) if option 4 was used

Large Downtime Option:

1. Optional (very recommended):  Make backups of your data mds files (likely in %progfiles%\MSSQL\Data)
2. Uninstall MSSQL
3. Install MSSQL Web Edition
4. Attach database(s) through the MSSQL interface (Right click attach in server manager)

I should note with the large downtime option.  If you website depend on something the standard edition uses you will not be able to get your websites back up and your will be down until you remove the options from the websites and for an indefinite period of time.

Comment: I'm tending to go with large downtime option. I'm guessing that I would back up DB's first, uninstall Standard Edition and any features not support by Web Edition, THEN install Web Edition and attach DB's? The process looks involved and error-prone: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955499